# Getting the last Process Date of SSAS Cube using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssas, analysis

I have a SSAS cube hosted on X server and have Y Cube on it.
How do I use Powershell to know Some status of Cube.VIZ
Status :-Online , Last Process Date

Answer (score 2):

There are at least four ways of doing that:

### PowerShell provider

Install the [`SqlServer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer) module and use the provider:

```
# Install-Module SqlServer

dir sqlserver:\sqlas\$ServerName\default\Databases\*\Cubes\* | Select Select Name, LastProcessed
```

I'm not a fan of this option because it requires a working WMI connection. This is often firewalled on production servers. But if it works, it can't be beat for convenience.

### SMO

Use [SQL Server Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.Connect($ServerName)
$server.Databases.Cubes | Select Name, LastProcessed
$server.Dispose()
```

SMO is convenient when it works, but depending on what you do it can be a little slow.

### XMLA

Metadata discovery can also be done using XMLA. This coughs up XML instead of a convenient object model, so it's not as easy as SMO, but it may under circumstances be faster. The [model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/schema-rowsets/ole-db-olap/mdschema-cubes-rowset) is not intuitive, however.

```
# Install-Module SqlServer

$query = @'
<Statement>SELECT cube_name, last_schema_update FROM $system.mdschema_cubes WHERE cube_source = 1</Statement>
'@
$result = [xml] (Invoke-ASCmd -Server $server -Query $query)
$result.return.root.row | select cube_name, last_schema_update
```

### ADOMD

This is halfway between SMO and issuing XMLA directly. You may need a [separate download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) (SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi).

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient") | Out-Null
$connection = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection "Data Source=$server;Catalog=$database" 
$connection.Open()
$connection.Cubes.Where{ $_.Type -eq 'Cube' } | Select Name, LastProcessed
```

This is more interesting for pure .NET applications than it is for PowerShell, as it's not really faster or more convenient than the other methods (and requires a download). I mention it for completeness.

Comment: Thanks that works ,Also,Sir do u know a method to check the status of the Cube,By that I mean if its Up or not,(Checking the status of service is not helpful here)

Comment: What do you mean by "up"? Probably the most reliable thing to do here is to connect and fire a dummy MDX query (`SELECT {} ON 0 FROM [Cube]`). If that succeeds, the cube is at least reachable, and if it's also processed, it should be usable.

Comment: Perfect ,Thanks :)

Comment: I was looking for a dummy mdx query,this (SELECT {} ON 0 FROM [Cube]) This is failing

Comment: Yeah, that's untested, just from the top of my head. Feel free to open a new question specifically for testing a cube's availability.